# Chrome renders repearting-linear-gradient unevenly

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am trying to make diagonal stripes, this works in all other browsers outside of chrome.

My chrome is up to date, running version 35.0.1916.114

My code:

```
background: repeating-linear-gradient(
        -45deg,
        #202020,
        #202020 5px,
        #191919 5px,
        #191919 10px
    );
```

Reners out the following...

[image]

How do I go about fixing this issue? I found this...https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71178, which seems to be the same issue and it is supposedly fixed, but clearly not.

Comment: I faced the exact same issue. Doesn't seem a fix is coming any time soon considering how long that bug has existed.

Comment: So Frustrating, but thanks